# Running a bash script from a different location but referencing where the script is located

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a script a while back that would do some simple install procedures in linux for people that don't like the command line, but it seems that they are running the script from a location (such as root). So I have a solution in mind but trying to find out how to reference where the file is located.

Example. 
I have a script called Install.sh in a folder /root/Server/Scripts/ which references itself by using the following:

```
SCRIPTSDIR=`pwd`
```

But I have come into problems with people running this script from root by doing sh Server/Scripts/Install.sh

How could I make SCRIPTS= something that references where the file is located, not where it is being run from?

Thanks, ask if you need more info!

Edit: All answers were good, I meant to put I needed absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get dir with

```
dirname $0
```

If your script is called with relative path, dirname will also return relative path. If you want to resolve it for some reason, you can do

```
readlink -f `dirname $0`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname $0)
```

If you need absolute path, then try:

```
cd $(dirname $0)
SCRIPTDIR=$(pwd)
cd -
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like:

```
fullscriptpath=$( dirname $0 )
```

Comment: ha wow, stackoverflow test of reflexes at it's finest :) (3 nearly identical answers within a few seconds of each other).